# Can someone help me understand how this code works? It was an example in class and I want to learn more efficiently

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

Write code that pushes 10 strings onto the stack (version 2), printing while it goes, then pops them off, printing while it removes.

```
import java.math.*;

public class StackTest {
 public static void main (String[] args){


 Stack2 stk = new Stack2("Stack");
       for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
 stk.push("Item: " + (i + 1));

 System.out.println("Pushing: Item: " + (i + 1));
 }
 System.out.println("\n" + stk.print());

      for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
 System.out.println("Popping: " + stk.pop());
 }
 System.out.println("\n" + stk.print());
 }
}
```

Comment: Which part of this code is not clear for you?

Comment: Have you tried adding break points and debugging the code?

Comment: For loop to go through 10 iterations with each iteration getting pushed to the stack and then getting printed out. It then does the same thing except instead of pushing items to the stack it "pops", or removes, them from the stack and prints out each as it does so.

Comment: In addition to what Brady said, there are two `stk.print` method calls that apparently print out the entire stack.  So the first one should print a stack with 10 elements, and the second one should print an empty stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a TestClass that tests your custom implementation of Stack. 
 Some key things that you'd need to know about a stack is that it is: 
LIFO (Last In First Out) data structure 
This is used in your browser. When you click your back button. 
Takes you to the last page you visited.

```
// A class in the default package

// Import java.math
import java.math.*;

// Class Name: StackTest
public class StackTest {

// Your main method: The entry point of your program
 public static void main (String[] args){

 // Creates an object Stack2 and references it to stk
 Stack2 stk = new Stack2("Stack");
 // Runs a for loop 10 times and pushes an element into the stack and prints the result into the console
       for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
         stk.push("Item: " + (i + 1));

         System.out.println("Pushing: Item: " + (i + 1));
 }
 // Prints your stack
 System.out.println("\n" + stk.print());

 // Runs a loop 10 times and pops each item of the stack out
 for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    System.out.println("Popping: " + stk.pop());
 }
 // Prints your stack
 System.out.println("\n" + stk.print());
 }
}
```

your console would read something like this:

```
Pushing Item: Item 1 
Pushing Item: Item 2 
Pushing Item: Item 3
Pushing Item: Item 4
Pushing Item: Item 5
Pushing Item: Item 6
Pushing Item: Item 7
Pushing Item: Item 8
Pushing Item: Item 9
Pushing Item: Item 10

Stack [Item 10, Item 9, Item 8, Item 7, Item 6, Item 5, Item 4, Item 3, Item 2, Item 1] < depending on what your Stack2 print() method does.
Popping: Item 10
Popping: Item 9 
Popping: Item 8
Popping: Item 7 
Popping: Item 6 
Popping: Item 5 
Popping: Item 4 
Popping: Item 3 
Popping: Item 2 
Popping: Item 1 
Stack []
```